# Issue getting correct POST data to save to mongodb from axios even though the console.log shows valid data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, vue.js, axios

I am having issues getting data to save to my mongoDB through a post. I am able to get it to show correctly in a console.log but i'm not getting the data to the DB successfully.

The axios code:

```
async created() {
    axios
      .get("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/?limit=2000")
      .then((res, err) => {
        if (res.status === 200) {
          this.$store.state.CMC = res.data[0].coins;
          // console.log(this.$store.state.CMC);

          // Send a POST request
          axios({
            method: "post",
            url: "http://localhost:5000/data",
            data: { coins: this.$store.state.CMC }
          }).catch(err, function() {
            console.log(err);
          });
        } else {
          console.log("Error: " + err);
        }
      });
  }
```

The express code for the POST:

```
app.post("/data", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  var Coins = new coins(req.body);
  Coins.save(req.body, function() {
    console.log("data was saved");
  });
});
```

Like i said, i can see the data being shown in the clog when i go to post it, it's just not saving correctly.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! if your `console.log(req.body)` works the way you wanted, have you checked your `var Coins = new coins(req.body);`? is `Coins` initialised properly?

Comment: I'd like to believe so but i'm not entirely sure. I've set up the model; but i'm not positive on the best way to do it with this data set. It returns an array with an object so i set the value as an array. This is the data set: https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/?limit=2000

Comment: const coinSchema = new Schema({
  CMC: Array
});

Comment: can you share the model schema for `coins`

Comment: I did, it's above your comment.